# Done/Fail is not called from overriden JQuery ajax XHR object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am overriding the JQuery Ajax XHR object with my custom implementation in order to 'fake' serquest to server and response from server.

I created simple example of what I try to achive in JS fiddle - in JS part I am defining very simple, global sendAjax() function that suppose to call server using $.ajax():

```
window.sendAjax = function() {

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "/ServerResource.txt"
    });

    jqxhr.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //this is never called
        alert("done !")
    });

    jqxhr.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //this is never called
        alert("fail " + errorThrown);
    });
}
```

also I try to substitute JQuery ajax xhr object using my own XHR where I replaced 'send()' method with my own implementation that suppose to return some data instead of XHTTPrequest - for the now in JSfiddle I am going to return imediately 'sucess' response. The problem is that the done or fail functions do not react on my response at all :(

Here is my redefinition of XHR

```
//reload jquery ajax
var originalXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhr: function () {
        var req = originalXhr();
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var promise = deferred.promise(req);
        if (req) {
            // Add your progress handler
            var _send = req.send;
            req.send = function (headers, complete) {
                //the one below does not work  
                setTimeout(function () {
                    deferred.resolve("Resolve promise", "OK", req);
                }, 200);
            }
            var _open = req.open;
            req.open = function () {
                console.log('OPEN AJAX called');
            }
        }

        return promise;
    }
});
```

I probably do something and $.Deferred does not work in the way I wont it, but I cannot figure what is wrong so far. 
Here is JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZwPXs/ - might be you have some ideas?

Best regards, Artem

Comment: `return deferred;` instead of `return promise;`

Comment: There's no valid `done` option for the `jQuery.ajax()` call, so remove that and see what happens.

Comment: 'return deferred;' will not work as it does not have ajax methods - it is a promise which expands the ajax with done,fail,always methods.
Also I edited the code above and removed one extra done() but it does not solve the issue as well